# Running "do script" synchronously in AppleScript

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, automator

I have the following AppleScript that I run on login:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Terminal"

        do script ".../MyScript.sh"

    end tell

    return input
end run
```

I run `MyScript.sh` like this because I want the output and prompts of the script displayed in a terminal window I can see and interact with. The external terminal window is required because the script is interactive and I need to provide it with non-static input (i.e. the input I give it is different each time the script is run) each time it is run.

The problem is that `do script` is run asyncronously, so if I simply add `quit` after the `do script` line the terminal window is closed right away. What I want to do is to block until `MyScript.sh` completes execution, *then* quit.

Bonus point if I can somehow store the `exit` code returned by `MyScript.h` and use it later in the AppleScript, and if I'm able to somehow force the `quit` so that I don't have to confirm that I want to close the terminal every time.

Comment: What are you trying to block *for* (i.e., what are you doing in the rest of the script?) It may help to invert things and make the "outer layer" a shell script that performs AppleScripts rather than vice versa.

Comment: The script does some auth stuff. I want to wait for it to finish executing (i.e. either the login either fully succeeds or fully fails) then I want to clean up the window for the user.

Comment: This is a hack, but if you add `kill $(ps aux | grep Terminal.app | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')` to the end of `MyScript.sh`, does that work?

Comment: There are better ways to quit Terminal or close the current Terminal window from the command line (such as via AppleScript, or with my `appswitch` :-).  Would investigate just putting that into `MyScript.sh`...

Comment: @beninato `grep`, `head`, **and** `awk` all in one go ?  That's utilising the most number of tools in the least effective way. As for the OP's problem, apart from performing authentication by way of AppleScript being inappropriate and extremely vulnerable/hackable, it sounds like you might be better off having a shell script be the main code driving all of this, which can run natively inside a terminal, and have the option of calling out to `osascript` _if_ you need some AppleScript functionality. That would likely kill all your birds with one bash.

Comment: @CJK there's 2FA built-in to the authentication, so I think it should be OK. I feel like I'm quite close using hte AppleScript method, though I'll think about whether I can push the logic further into the script. Basically, I need it to run at startup and an AppleScript seemed like the best way